# flexdashboard page layout error

Tags: r, r-markdown, flexdashboard

After updating R Version from 3.3.3 to 3.4.2 my flexdashbords dont work anymore

When running that simple example:

````
---
title: "Flexdash Layout Test"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
```

Page 1
===================================================

Column 1 {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r}
print('Chart A')
```

Column 2 {data-width=350}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart B

```{r}
print('Chart B')
```

Page 2
===============================================

### Chart C

```{r}
print('Chart C')
```
````

The result looks like this:
[flexdash layout error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2EUY.png)

So obviously the formatting syntax does not work.

Thank you in advance for any hint to solve that problem

EDIT:
When I try that example and choose html as output, the formatting result looks like expected.

```
---
title: "Rmd Formatierung Test"
output: html_document
---

Plain text   

End a line with two spaces  
to start a new paragraph.   
*italics* and _italics_   
**bold** and __bold__   
superscript^2^   
~~strikethrough~~   
[link](www.rstudio.com)  

# Header 1   

## Header 2
```

So the error is definitely related to flexdashboard

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Austria.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Austria.1252       LC_MONETARY=German_Austria.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=German_Austria.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] flexdashboard_0.5

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.2  backports_1.1.1 magrittr_1.5    rprojroot_1.2     htmltools_0.3.6 tools_3.4.2    
[7] yaml_2.1.14     Rcpp_0.12.13    stringi_1.1.5   rmarkdown_1.7    knitr_1.17      jsonlite_1.5   
[13] stringr_1.2.0   digest_0.6.12   evaluate_0.10.1
```

Comment: your example works for me maybe you should reinstall the package

Comment: I have the same problem with Microsoft R Client 3.4.1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is documented here : https://github.com/rstudio/flexdashboard/pull/150

Basically, pandoc 2.0 defaults to html5 instead of html by default which breaks flexdashboard layout.

You have two options:

1) Downgrade to pandoc 1.x

2) Install the Github package until it gets pushed to CRAN. This fixed the issue for me.

```
remove.packages("flexdashboard")
install.packages("devtools")
library("devtools")
install_github("rstudio/flexdashboard")
```

Comment: Just tried your proposed option Nr 2) - installed the flexdashboard package from github solved the problem. Thank you Vincent.